# PHPMailer gives an error when sending mails with the Gmail smtp server

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm using phpmailer in a selfmade template/mail function:

```
<?php  
require_once(__DIR__.'/../../vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
function sendTemplateMail($body, $data, $subject, $receiver, $sender){
$template = Timber::compile($body, $data);
sendMail($template, $subject, $receiver, $sender);
}  

function sendMail($template, $subject, $receiver, $sender){

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                        // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP     // TCP port to connect to

$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "**";
$mail->Password = "**";

$mail->setFrom($sender);
$mail->addAddress($receiver);     // Add a recipient
$mail->addReplyTo($sender);

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $template;
$mail->AltBody = $template; //$mail->AltBody = $template; //

return $mail->send();
}
```

In my project the username and password are correct because they worked before. But now I get an error that the smtp is not connected.
fatal error: Uncaught phpmailerException: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

Comment: what is the entire error message?

Comment: The error is too long to copy in the comments

Comment: fatal error: Uncaught phpmailerException: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

Comment: @JornReed You can edit your question and place the error there

Comment: I added the error

Comment: Try this, add the sentence to sendMail function:     $mail->SMTPOptions = array('ssl' => array('verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false, 'allow_self_signed' => true));

Comment: Thanks!, It worked before without your line of code, why doesn't it work without now?

Comment: Adding that code is a bad idea. It's exposing your app to security problems, defeating the point of using encryption. There has been a recent spike of this problem because gmail changed its certificate to one that was signed by a root CA certificate that many don't apparently have (so PHP itself can't verify the certificate presented by gmail), so you most likely need to update your CA certificate store, which is described in [the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#certificate-verification-failure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, add the sentence to sendMail function:

```
   $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
            'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true
            )
        );
```

You can allow insecure connections via the SMTPOptions property introduced in PHPMailer 5.2.10 (it's possible to do this by subclassing the SMTP class in earlier versions), **though this is not recommended** as it defeats much of the point of using a secure transport at all.

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#php-56-certificate-verification-failure

**This should be a temporary solution.**

Comment: Thank you, i work with phpmailer often, but somehow after a couple of weeks my code didn't work anymore. I know how to set up phpmailer, but i'm not good with smtp :(